# Ear Deployment is failing with null module after upgrading to Hibernate 5.3 from 5.2, i am using wweblogic 12c 12.1.3

Tags: java, hibernate, weblogic12c, cglib

I am migrating hibernate to 5.3.12.Final from 5.2.18.Finl after doing so when I try to deploy my ear to weblogic 12.1.3 it throws following error:

```
weblogic.application.ModuleException: null
null
at    weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.createModuleException(WebAppModule.java:1824)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.init(WebAppModule.java:270)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.init(WebAppModule.java:682)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.init(ScopedModuleDriver.java:162)
at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.init(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:98)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at com.bea.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.bea.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at weblogic.application.utils.annotation.ClassInfoImpl.<init>    (ClassInfoImpl.java:41)
at weblogic.application.utils.annotation.ClassfinderClassInfos.polulateOneClassInfo(ClassfinderClassInfos.java:240)
at weblogic.application.utils.annotation.ClassfinderClassInfos.populateClassInfos(ClassfinderClassInfos.java:193)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

I am also using spring 4.2.3 , java 8,

I have tried to exluce cglib and asm liberary from hibernate-core jar and also tried to manually upgrade the version of a 3.1 to a 6.2.1, nothing worked.
I also tried to provide asm liberary reference is Weblogic-application.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you are using a class file version that the weblogic server does not support. ASM throws this exception if the class files were compiled with a Java version it does not recognize. Since ASM seems to be shaded, you need to probably upgrade weblogic and the underlying JVM.

Comment: Seems like some class file in your application is Java 9+ then.

Comment: In my application I don't thinks so, while in  Hibernate it has provided support for JDK 11, and JDK 9. But it shouldn't break the existing behaviour for java 8. Although when I tried to deploy on 12.2.1 it was successfully deployed. Thanks man !

Comment: More and more jars include a module-info class to support the module system. This class file cannot be read by old versions of ASM, this might be the problem. I assume that Weblogic adopted to this in an update. Maybe you find a description in its change log.